# How to make Xamarin image expand vertically using VerticalOptions FillAndExpand

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning the below Xamarin code, I would like to make each image fulfills its cell. I already tried `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`.
But it doesn't work. How to solve it?

```
<Grid x:Name="initialpagelayout" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon01"></Image>
            <Image BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon02"></Image>
            <Image BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon03"></Image>
            <Image BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon04"></Image>
            <Image BackgroundColor="Pink" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon05"></Image>
            <Image BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon06"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon07"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon08"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon09"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon10"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon11"></Image>
            <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon12"></Image>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

**UPDATE1**

I added `Aspect="Fill"` into each `<Image>`, and I get the below:
[image: update1]

It works well but I notice there is a blank space above the first row, but I don't have any placeholder there,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Guru.Pwa.Mobile.Initial">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="initialpagelayout" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon01"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon02"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon03"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon04"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon05"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon06"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon07"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon08"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon09"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MyIcon10"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyIcon11"></Image>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyIcon12"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How to remove it?

Comment: You can set how to fill the space via the Image's aspect ratio setting, but not sure if you are looking to just "center" the image in the cell or actually scale it and clip it vertically or horizontally since the aspect ratio of your cells appears to not match your image's aspect ratio.

Comment: @SushiHangover I would like to scale it and clip it vertically due to the ratio

Comment: As @SushiHangover said, you should use the [Aspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.image.aspect?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Image_Aspect) property

Comment: I made an update, using Aspect=Fill, and it works, not sure what is the Image's aspect ratio setting? And there is a blank area above the first row, how to remove it?

Comment: I figure it out, adding NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" to the <ContentPage> and that blank space get removed.